# DELETE FROM inside a PL/SQL Procedure Block

Tags: oracle, plsql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am currently trying to delete all rows of a table that is linked to another one via foreign key.

My Code looks kinda like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure test
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM person;
End;
/
```

The Errors says: ora-02292 integrity constraint violated - child record found

When I try to just diable the constraints then it says i cant 'ALTER' the table.

What do i have to do/change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't just *disable* constraint, because you'll leave child records *orphans* (there will be NO parent record for them). What will you do, then?

Correct way to handle it is to

- delete children first
- delete parents last

If foreign key constraint was created with the `on delete cascade` option, database would handle it for you.

---

P.S. As of "you can't ALTER the table" - that's not an Oracle error message. They have their codes, such as `ORA-06550`. It is difficult to guess what you actually did, and - if I had to guess - I'd say that you tried to do that within  the procedure:

```
SQL> create table temp (id number constraint pkt primary key);

Table created.

SQL> begin
  2    alter table temp disable constraint pkt;
  3  end;
  4  /
  alter table temp disable constraint pkt;
  *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the following:
( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
raise return select update while with <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
```

You'll need dynamic SQL to do that:

```
SQL> begin
  2    execute immediate 'alter table temp disable constraint pkt';
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

But, once again, that's not the way you should handle this situation.